# Why don't I see any increase in my run speed when I equip an item with Fleet Primal Diamond?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a head item with a Fleet Primal Diamond equipped in the meta socket. The text of Fleet Primal Diamond says: "+27 mastery and minor run speed increase". However, when I equip it, I don't see any change in the run speed reported in the stats window. It says 110% both before and after. Does this gem not work anymore? Am I too high level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be remnant of the net stealth nerf from 6.0.2:

Read these forum discussion on the issue: http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/16646034684#1
http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/16490709295?page=2#25

Blizzard changed the movement speed buffs without documenting them.